# How to create vertical axis lines when the chart type can change?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, updates

I am trying to create the axis lines that can be seen in this [d3.js example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/population.html) with the chart from this [d3.js example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stack.html).

I am new to d3.js and I am struggling with creating both the horizontal lines and refreshing/updating the labels when the graph type changes.

How do I create the vertical lines and how can I update them when the graph type changes?

Comment: take a look at this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/ - it shows you to handle both transitions and updates in a nice way. True - it's not 100% what you're looking for, both you need to understand the process first.